# Implementing Custom Authentication with Tomcat

Tags: authentication, tomcat, jaas

Hey all,
      I'm using Tomcat 6.0.14 and would like to know to implement a system that would allow us to send users a link say mysite.com?token=12345678912334333(long string continued) but that would allow the user to be logged in automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you have other reasons specific to Tomcat, or you are unable to modify your web application, then it might be easiest to use a custom filter to do the authentication (JAAS or otherwise). For example:

- http://www.kopz.org/public/documents/tomcat/jaasintomcat.html
- http://securityfilter.sourceforge.net/

With a custom filter, you could authenticate in whatever way you wanted to in a relatively straightforward way.

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request,
                     ServletResponse response,
                     FilterChain chain) 
  throws IOException, ServletException {

    String token = request.getParameter("token");
    if (token != null) {
      doAuthentication(token);
    }

    chain.doFilter(request, wrapper);
}
```

You tagged with JAAS. That's different than just authenticating with a simple token, but if that's what you are looking for, are you familiar with Tomcat's JAASRealm? You would just have to write your own [LoginModule](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/security/jaas/JAASLMDevGuide.html) to authenticate the token.

- http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/realm-howto.html#JAASRealm

It probably goes without saying that using token based login via E-mail is inherently insecure, and so is not appropriate for all types of applications.

Comment: I actually was looking at JAASRealm, but with that I'm not sure how to set request.getRemoteUser. It appears that this Securityfilter.org solution some how does it. I could change our sites authentication to use request.getPrincipal pretty easily. Just wondering if there's an easy way of writing request.getRemoteUser() I guess

Comment: The request.getRemoteUser was meant for retrieving authentication as provided by the container(Tomcat). JAAS is different.  It's difficult to programmatically feed the JAAS authenticated user/principal/subject back to the container so that getRemoteUser can be used. In Tomcat, I think it requires writing a custom valve or some other low level hook. Unless you really need getRemoteUser, it might be easier to store the user/principal/subject in the session yourself and retrieve it directly from the session where needed in your servlet code.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to implement the logic by yourself, i.e. the link guide the user to a servlet or something like that which recognize that link, join it with the user, create a session object and redirect the user inside your app.

Hope this helps